# Filter filenames from text file with other data on same line

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that I created using the robocopy workaround for long filenames.

Each line (except from the job footer) contains the following
"New Line" Size Date Time FullName

The next two lines are from the text file.

```
New File           4.5 m 2013/05/08 13:25:00    e:\data\Data\aswMBR.exe  
New File          287032 2009/06/26 07:07:42    e:\data\Data\AutodeskDesignRevSetup.exe
```

How can I "filter" the Fullname (starting with ' e:\'  ) from each line?

I tried using .split  but couldn't get it to work with the 'e:\' as delimiter.

Comment: Did you try a split on either space or tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the file for lines containing `New File`, split them at tabs, and keep last element from each split line (index -1):

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\robocopy.log' |
  ? { $_ -match '^\s*new file' } |
  % { $_.Split("`t")[-1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to match fullname.

If you want to get only fullname:

```
(Get-Content file.txt | Select-String 'e:\\.*').Matches.Value
```

If you want to remove fullname:

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\se:\\.*'}
```

Comment: The code for getting the fullname returns nothing.  The remove fullname code works correctly :)

Comment: Weird. I saved your sample lines to file.txt and it works for me.